# Looking for the best way to configure my server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I'm in the process of changing the network in my company.
I'd like to make it work with a domain name, DNS server using
Active Directory.
The server will work on Windows 2008 Server.
How do I choose the FQDN?
How do I make the Workstations member of the Domain (stupid question, I guess it's simple!)?
The VPN is configured through the Router, isn't it better directly on the server?
What at all do I have to configure in order to migrate the actual IP network to the Domain system?
Thanks for the answers.

Edit--

The company is constituted with 10 Workstations and 3 servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of your Active Directory Domain name is entirely up to you. Its common to use the  name of your company, or department of the company, but its not rigid. You can use an extension for the domain (.com, .net etc), however it is common practise to use the .local extension as this makes the domain distinct from internet based domains and non-routeabele.

Connecting workstations to a domain is done by right clicking on my computer, going to Compuer Name and setting this to the domain. In Vista it is in the system pane.

Setting up a correctly configured AD domain can be a complicated process, you need to ensure your DNS is setup correctly, user accounts are setup etc. I would suggest you do some reading, and setup a test environment to experiment with before you go live with your changes.

An excellent begginers guide to setting up AD can be found [here](http://www.petri.co.il/how_to_install_active_directory_on_windows_2003.htm)

As for the VPN, using a VPN through the router has some advantages, its not dependant on any of your servers and will give you access to you whole network by default, however it needs its own authentication accounts (unless you use RADIUS), where as setting up a VPN server on your domain could then use your active directory accounts.

Comment: If you have, or are likely to have any Apple Macs in your environment, or any other service (iTunes) that uses mDNS (Multicast-DNS), the .local domain is highly discouraged as it conflicts with the conventional implementation of mDNS. An appropriate alternative is often .lan in my experience.